# android-change button background color after clicked

Tags: android, android-button

Problem: I want to change the background color of a button after it has been pressed.

It's a simple problem, but I have spent a lot of time googling this and I can't seem to find a solution. They all refer to the same XML that appears below.

My XML is as follows:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/black_button_pressed" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/black_button_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/black_button_normal"/>
</selector>
```

So, when a person hovers over a button, it'll appear grayed out. When a person clicks on a button, the button's background should be grayed out after the click, but I can't seem to get it grayed out. It returns to the normal state after the press.

Do you guys have any tips and/or pointers to help me?

Comment: It's supposed to return to it's normal state after it's been clicked. If you want it to permanently stay in the clicked state you'll have to use Russ's answer below. However, you'll have to set the background resource back to that XML file if you want the user to be able to click it again with the same animation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In android, state of the UI will not persist after the event is completed. For example, you can handle the `button` `click` event and highlight the button but it returns to its normal state once the Up event is fired. So, the only option as far as i know is, change the background of the button by setting a different `drawable resource`.

```
btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_selected_blue);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works (in your onClick handler):

```
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_selected);
```

There may be a nicer way however.